# Program keeps giving me the "core dump", though i can't find why

Tags: string, struct, coredump

So, i wrote this program which receives as input a string, which consists of surname and name, written like this: "james:lebron". The program should copy surname in the surname variable of the struct, same goes for the name. No compilation errors, just the core dump error. Somebody can please explain me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct author{

    char *name;
    char *surname;
    };

typedef struct author author_t;

author_t separate(char *string);

int main(void){

    char *name_surname;
    printf("Inserisci nome e cognome: ");
    gets(name_surname);
    separate(name_surname);
    }

author_t separate(char *string){

    int i, n=0;
    author_t temp;
    for(i=0; i<(strlen(string)-1); i++){

        while(string[i]!=':')
        n++;
        strncpy(temp.surname, string, n);
        strncpy(temp.name, &string[n+2], (strlen(string)-n-2));
        }

    return(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

off teh top of my head Id say incrementing n is not a good idea as n i steh number of items to copy not the position in the string.

Comment: yeah, but incrementing n serves me as, when ":" is encountered, n is the numbers of characters to be copied

Comment: I didnt thing the struct declaration actually made an instance as it doesnt have a name after the ;

Comment: I didnt think the struct declaration actually made an instance (Storage) as it doesnt have a name after the ; and doesnt declare a variable. I would also advise not to use string as a variable name - it could be used internally in the compiler, ie like a protected name 'system' 'variable'. don't use these or expect the unexpected...

Answer (score 0):

```
struct author{

char *name;
char *surname;
};
....
int i, n=0;
author_t temp;
for(i=0; i<(strlen(string)-1); i++){

    while(string[i]!=':')
    n++;
    strncpy(temp.surname, string, n);
    strncpy(temp.name, &string[n+2], (strlen(string)-n-2));
    }
```

You cannot copy into tmp.surname or temp.name, as you did not reserve any memory yet. (Note that `strncpy` does not reserve memory, it just copies.) `char *name` only reserves space for a pointer, not the actual string. User `char name[30]` or so, or assign memory later like this:

```
author_t auth;
auth.name = (char *) malloc(30);
```

(same for surname, of course)